# hasMany relationship return null with mongodb (jenssegers) laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, relationship, jenssegers-mongodb, laravel-mongodb

i have laravel 8 project with jenssegers (Mongodb Database)
but my hasMany relationship not work between Product & Category Model
my Product mongo object :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5dcaafb8eaec3701a2774d29")
"category_ids" : [ 
    ObjectId("5dcaacbfeaec37018b508a39"), 
    ObjectId("5dcaacbfeaec37018b508a5d")
]}
```

and my Category mongo object :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5dcaacbfeaec37018b508a39"),
"title" : "category test",
"slug" : "wordpress-plugins"
```

}

my Product model code :

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'category_ids', '_id');
}
```

but below code return null :

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->where('_id', $id)->first();
    dd($product->categories);
```

please help me , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you added `category_ids` in product field, I suppose you mean Product belongs to many Categories, and each Category can have many Products attached to it. So the relationship should be declared differently. That is:

- Create a pivot Model `CategoryPost` with table/collection `categories_posts`
- Let the collection `categories_posts` store `product_id` and `category_id` to show that a Product belongs to that Category (instead of saving the category ids in `product` collection as array)
- Define your relationship in Product Model as follows

```
// This is what you should rather have in your Product Model
public function categories() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'categories_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}

// While in your Category Model, you can have this if you wish to get all products belonging to a category using the Category instance
public function products() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class, 'categories_posts', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$this->belongsToMany` relation in both the modals.

```
public function categories() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

public function products() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```